# How to retrieve AES key using alias from JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, aes, keytool, jboss-eap-6

I would like to create a utility that retrieves AES key from keystore. I have followed the instructions in [this article](http://www.ensor.cc/2014/02/aes-256-encryption-with-java-and-jceks.html) so I created the keystore with the following command

```
keytool -genseckey -keystore path_to_filestore/jbvault.keystore -storetype jceks -storepass some_password -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -alias jbvault
```

and was able to get the key using the alias with the following code

```
String password = "some_password";
File file = new File("path_to_filestore/jbvault.keystore");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), password.toCharArrray());
if(keyStore.containsAlias("jbvault"))
{
    Key key = keyStore.getKey("jbvault", password.toCharArray());
}
```

This has worked fine but I would like to use the same keystore as password vault on JBoss EAP 6.4 as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Security_Guide/Mask_the_Keystore_Password_and_Initialize_the_Password_Vault..html) and get the same key using the alias from within my web application but have not been able to achieve that. I have tried using SecurityVaultUtil but it only provides functionality to retrieve String value based on keys added to the the keystore.

Thanks in advance